# React-Native on Genymotion: How to I make 'dev settings / debug server host & port' persistent?

Tags: react-native, genymotion

For a react native application, I am defining in genymotion the value for dev settings / debug server host & port and when I restart the virtual device, it is cleared. Is there any way to make it persistent?

(running genymotion 3.0 on windows 10)

*note: I have posted this question a while ago, but I specified only the 'genymotion' tag, thinking that the issue is related to genymotion. However, the support guys  of genymotion told me that it is related to the react-native app. This is why I am posting again, with the 'react native' tag.*